# Number of Sylow $3$ subgroups of $S_4$,not knowing the structure of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

I am trying to find out the number of Sylow $3$ subgroups of $S_4$,
Order of $S_4$ is $24$,we write $24$ as $24=2*2*2*3$,
so we both have sylow $2$ subgroups and  sylow $3$ subgroups.
Let $n_2$ and $n_3$ are their respective numbers.
By using Sylow's 1st Theorem The possible values of  $n_3$ are $1,4$ and for $n_2=1,3$.We know $S_4$ has order $3$ for the elements $ (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,1),(1,2,4)$,Each of them  generates distinct cyclic subgroups of $S_4$,Thus we get $n_3=4$.Now we can think each of Sylow $2$ subgroups as the rotation,reflection of a square having vertices $1,2,3,4$ about the axes through the center which is $D_4$.We get such three Sylow $3$ subgroups ie.$n_2=3$.I have solved  my problem using the structure of $S_4$,But suppose I have  no such idea on the  algebraic structure of $S_4$ and trying to do it using only Sylow's Theorems.can I be successful?Is it necessary to study the algebraic structure of any  Symmetric group to find it's Sylow $p$ subgroups?

Comment: There are many (nonisomorphic) groups of order 24, and they don't all have the same number of Sylow-3 subgroups – you need to know something about the structure of $S_4$.

Comment: @Gerrry Myerson Is it  sufficient to know only the elements of $S_4$ and their orders to  find out  number off Sylow $2$subgroups and Sylow $3$ subgroups?

Comment: Since the 3-Sylows have order 3, the number of 3-Sylows is half the number of elements of order 3. But the 2-Sylows have order 8, and there are several groups of order 8, with different numbers of elements of orders 2, 4, and 8, so that's going to be harder to get, if all you know is the number of elements of each order.

Comment: Wouldnʻt the 3rd Sylow Theorem remedy this?